# TinyMCE keeps adding default video width and height

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've got a video pasted into tinymce but I need to stop it defining the dimensions automatically as I'd like to control them via css instead.

So I paste in:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" preload="" controls="controls" poster="/video/video.png"><source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

But then tinymce automatically pastes in annoying default dimensions for me and it ends up being:

```
<video width="300" height="150" id="sampleMovie" preload="" controls="controls" poster="/video/video.png">
<source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

Which I really, really don't want. Is there a way to stop this?

In my init code I've already got:

```
relative_urls: false,
cleanup: false,
verify_html : false,
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I need to stop it from doing this too, it's against WCAG accessibility guidelines to use height and width attributes for styling. It's doing it to my iframes.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to prevent the default by adding height="auto".

Answer (score 0):

**TinyMCE 4.0.11 - Automatically remove width and height attributes from img elements inserted via the img plugin**

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function(args) {
        editor = args.target;

        editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
            if (e && e.element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                tinyMCE.DOM.setAttribs(e.element, {'width': null, 'height': null});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/simshaun/7592631

Comment: This question is about `video` width and height NOT `img` width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not THE answer but I had a similar dilemma with `<IFRAME>`.  The workaround I settled with is disabling the width/height attribute as a valid attribute by doing so:

```
extended_valid_elements : "iframe[style|src|class]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly an answer to this question, but I only noticed after migrating to TinyMCE 6 that a height attribute with a default value of 150 was automatically added when it was missing. You can prevent the default by adding height="".